# Java Scanner.hasNextLine() doesn't detect an empty line?

Tags: java

Suppose I've the following file

```
Hej Hej Hej
A A A A
```

with a line break after the line with A's.

My problem is that the code

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (in.hasNextLine()) {
        out.println(line);
    }
    else {
        out.print(line);
    }
}
```

doesn't detect this extra line in `in.hasNextLine()`, so I miss the line break in the ouput file (I'm doing a file concatenation program). What could the problem be?

Answer (score 5):

Your invoking `.hasNextLine()` twice, while you're reading the "next line" just once.

Your code should rather be:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();        
    out.println(line);            
}
```

Or, if you want to check within the loop *again* for next line existence, you should do this (which I find not clean enough, because it does exactly the same as the snippet above):

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = in.nextLine();
        out.println(line);
    } else {
        out.print(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: `out.print` should be `out.println` in your first snippet.

Comment: This doesn't differentiate between a file that ends with a newline, and one where the last line is not terminated. I think that's what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yes that is what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.getLine()` reads all characters on the currently line, *including* the line terminator (if there is one), and then it *discards* the line terminator. Using this method, there is no way of knowing if the file ends with or without a line terminator.

If you are writing a file concatenation program, why do you want to read line-by-line? Doing so could cause loss of data; for example, your output file would use the platform-default line terminator (e.g. "\r\n" or "\n") irrespective of which line terminator your input files were using.

It would make more sense to read and write the files as a stream of bytes, e.g. using `InputStream.read(byte[])`. Even better, use `java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, OutputStream out)` which was newly introduced in Java 7 and does all the hard work for you.

One word of caution, however, is that if the files you want to concatenate are text files with different character encodings, you'll want to convert them to all use the same encoding in the output file. In that case, use a `FileReader` and a Writer instead.